# anonymizing multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have semi-anonmyous userId's of the form

```
userID data
foo1  {"payload":"blah"}
foo2 {"payload": "blah2"}
```

I want to pseduo-anonmyize it , turn `foo1` and `foo2` to `bar100` and `bar105` and so on (so change `foo` to `bar` and multiply the number by 5).

I have `userId` in multiple tables in the database so i would like to do this across all the tables.

I can use `substring()` function to get the string and then multiply the number but I am struggling with the exact sql query. Additionally, I need to convert this to a function or something that I can apply to multiple tables.

help is appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Why don't you use a UUID? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html

Comment: UUID would be fine too but i need to do the mapping multiple times